# Combine fields in transformation from "get rows from result" + info from a query

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a PDI transformation that gets 3 fields from a result row:

- SEARCH_VALUE
- Asset
- IP_V4_Address

The next hop is a table input that searches based on search value and returns one column value, something like `abcd-1234`.

`SELECT DISTINCT p.txt_reqID FROM ...`

Now, after my table input runs, the resulting stream only has 1 column (the `txt_reqID`).  I'd like my output stream to have 4 columns - the original 3 + the new one from the table input.  How do I do that?

Here is the transformation and the input row structure:

[image: Transform and input row structure]

This is the table input setup:

[image: Table input]

I'm only able to access the `txt_reqID` field after the table input, I can't figure out how to tell it to pass the other 3 through.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having `Select values` step after the `Get rows from result` step. `Select Values` is required to duplicate your **SEARCH_VALUE** as you need this field in both **SELECT** and in the **WHERE** clause and also it can be used to reorder the fields before table input.

In `Table input` you can use the query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.txt_reqId, ? as SearchValue, ? as Asset, ? as IPV4 address 
FROM ... WHERE d.value like ?
```

Here is the sample for the same
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJY4o.png)